# React: How to assign key based on state counter and increment state counter in mapping?

Tags: reactjs, key

I'm building a react App that displays a list of items (the component name is 'el'). I would like each item to contain a unique key that is simply a counter (called 'rank' here) that the app increments for each item. I'm currently successfully assigning rank as the key in the mapping, but I don't know how to make to increment it so it's unique for each one. Is this possible? Should I use a for loop of some sort instead of map()?

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someList:[/*Some List of Elements*/],
      rank:0,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const {myList, rank} = this.state;
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row mb-5">
            <div className="col">
              <ul className="list-group" id="list">
                {myList.map(
                  (el) => <AListElement id={el.id} text={el.text} key={rank}/>
                )}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map()` function comes with a unique index counter parameter for each item:

```
{myList.map(
  (el, index) => <AListElement id={el.id} text={el.text} key={index}/>
)}
```

Comment: is bad practice to use index as key.

Answer (score 1):

`key` attribute is for identifying the element uniquely. You don't have to maintain a state to pass to `key`.

`.map()` method has `index` as the second param and you can pass it as a key as Shawn has mentioned in his answer. But generally, it's a good idea to append a unique string to the `index` and pass it to the key prop.

```
{myList.map(
  (el, i) => <AListElement id={el.id} text={el.text} key={`el_${el.id}_${i}`}/>
)}
```

As to why it's important to not use just `index` as key prop

> key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM elements. What happens if you push an item to the list or remove something in the middle? If the key is same as before React assumes that the DOM element represents the same component as before. But that is no longer true.

Here's an elaborate write-up with an example.

[Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Answer (score 1):

**[The React docs](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key)** explicitly mention that using an array index is not a good idea. This is because when the array order changes (and all the inner components re-render), the keys will also change. It's also not performant as the contents within each array item have to be repopulated.

Ultimately the issue is with order and performance. React won't be able to track the life of each component, which will create bugs if your map items rely on anymore than one piece of state.

If we do not include a key, ***React by default will include a key with the value of the array index***. So while the answer above removes the error, it doesn't have any other benefits and goes against Reacts advice.

The docs tell us that keys should never change on re-render and that we should get our keys from a database, or pre-supplied ids in the array.

When using local data to provide keys React has this to say.

> Locally generated data: If your data is generated and persisted locally (e.g. notes in a note-taking app), use an incrementing counter, crypto.randomUUID() or a package like uuid when creating items.

**It does mention about using an incrementing counter though**.

Here is one solution. Imagine we have some data with ids provided

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    task: "ironing"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    task: "wash dishes"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    task: "shopping"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    task: "exercise"
  }
]
```

It's not in order which makes it more like what we might see in the real world. Let's try this counter function.

```js
function generateID(data) {
  let idCount = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let current = data[i].id;
    if (current > idCount) {
      idCount = current + 1
    }
  }
  return idCount
}

// We can make this more concise with a reducer function

function generateID(data) {
  return data.reduce((final, current) => {
    return current.id > final 
    ? final = (current.id + 1) : final
  }, 0)
}
```

It's a simple function that should always be able to provide a value one higher than the highest number provided by `data[i].id`

Let's imagine we're adding an item

```js
function addTask(data, task) {
  return [...data, task]
}

// We can now call it

const newData = addTask(data, {
  id: generateID(data),
  task: "sleep"
})
```

Even if we're changing the order around in our array, ***React shouldn't have any problem keeping track of each array elements lifecycle***.